# How to update an existing entity in nopCommerce 2.5 (MVC)?

Tags: nopcommerce

How to update an existing entity in nopCommerce 2.5 (MVC)?

I did makes changes to class under Nop.Data > Mapping folder. But it does not created the column to database after I run the application. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Can't you just create the column yourself?

Comment: It uses the Entity Framework Code First approach.

Comment: What is your point? Using EFCF does not entail checking if the existing database is aligned with the code on every request (imagine the overhead of that). Have you tried a fresh install after your mapping changes?

Comment: I am new to nopCommerce and trying to learn how it works. I am not sure how to start fresh installation. If I start the fresh installation then what happens to existing data? Do I need to back and restore the data?

Comment: As I said, I think the easiest way would be to create the column manually.

Comment: Ok. I was thinking there should  be some way in which EFCF will check for the schema updates.I read more about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is the resource created by the Nop team to guide you through updating the solution/entity

http://www.nopcommerce.com/docs/73/updating-an-existing-entity-how-to-add-a-new-property.aspx

Answer (score 0):

add new property in Nop.Core\Domain folder.

**Note:** Nop.Data > Mapping is for mapping between your table and your entity classes.

Add new column in your table manually.
**Manually add column in table is necessary.**

Change your Controller and View as per your requirement.

If you want to get to more detail about [Add Custom Field In NopCommerce Table](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=20&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiLlJDc0PfOAhWMrI8KHXLWDf44ChAWCE8wCQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lateshtclick.com%2Fblogpost%2Fhow-to-add-new-column-in-existing-table-in-nopcommerce&usg=AFQjCNEkDPFiH-otOP_9SaHCp9-UMwsI5w&sig2=j00kZ9povXzPnR5gnDcuMQ&bvm=bv.131783435,d.c2I)